# Dúvida em editar um título para algo mais apropriado e técnico

Tags: debate

Nesse tópico: [Como colocar PHP dentro de um echo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42577/como-colocar-php-dentro-de-um-echo)

Eu compreendo que um novato na linguagem cometa essa gafe "colocar php dentro de um echo"..
Ok, apesar de soar bizarro para um experiente, ok, é compreensível.

A dúvida é, é válido editar casos assim para um termo mais apropriado ou é melhor manter da forma original?

Uma vantagem da forma original é que outros novatos provavelmente e eventualmente poderão ter a mesma dúvida e, por falta de experiência, não saberão como descrever.

Desvantagem, é bizarro.. rsrs pois, logicamente, não faz sentido algum colocar php dentro da própria sintaxe php.

O motivo de eu julgar como estranho é que o título traz ambiguidade.
A princípio, antes de ler o contexto, somente lendo o título, eu imaginei duas coisas
 1. O sujeito quer concatenar variável. (95%)
 2. O sujeito quer parsear algum valor PHP provindo de eval ou coisa do tipo (5%)

Então, editar ou não?

Eu imagino que um título melhor seria "como concatenar variável php num echo".
Um problema em editar dessa forma, como expliquei acima, é que o termo "concatenar", para  um novato, é um termo desconhecido  e não saberá nem como pesquisar antes de abrir uma nova pergunta e provavelmente abrirá perguntas duplicadas.

Uma alternativa que talvez seja melhor é manter o título original e simplesmente adicionar a palavra "concatenar" nas tags.

É permitido adicionar essa palavra nas tags?

Comment: O titulo era `Preciso colocar um PHP em um Echo, podem ajudar?` só tentei deixa-lo mais claro, realmente pode ser uma gafe, mas já vi usuários com a mesma duvida e achei que um titulo melhor poderia ajudar evitar perguntas duplicatas, mas se o titulo não fizer sentido, por favor solicite um rollback.

Comment: Não sabia que já estava editado.. Achei que fosse original. Alias, agora que comentou, acho que o original estava melhor, só precisando remover o trecho ", podem ajudar?"

Comment: mas a questão mesmo é sobre incluir a palavra "concatenar" como uma tag.

Comment: A ok, entendi. Eu pessoalmente discordo de editar, pois o autor nem sabia sobre concatenar quando fez a pergunta e por incrível que pareça está duvida é comum entre novatos, portanto melhor um título que possa ser encontrado pelos usuários novatos e uma resposta que explique como funciona a linguagem especifica.