# Edição de título para facilitar as buscas

Tags: debate, perguntas, edição, título

Tem uma pergunta [Cálculo em JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66607/c%C3%A1lculo-em-javascript/66612#66612), onde a dificuldade do autor era realizar um cálculo onde o "número" continha `,`, daí o resultado era um `NaN`.

Então estive pensando: Podemos/devemos alterar o título da pergunta para algo que melhore as buscas?

Eu dei uma olhada no "debate" [Dúvida em editar um título para algo mais apropriado e técnico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2679/d%C3%BAvida-em-editar-um-t%C3%ADtulo-para-algo-mais-apropriado-e-t%C3%A9cnico), porém não creio que foi um debate, foi algo muito específico para a pergunta da questão.

A minha dúvida é mais referente a SEO, pois se eu estivesse com um problema semelhante a questão do cálculo que eu mencionei, eu pesquisaria algo como `javascript calculo retorna NaN`.

Este é apenas um exemplo, se você pesquisar `ajuda` no StackOverflow terá `n` casos parecidos. É claro que quando eu estou com problema eu não pesquiso `ajuda javascript` como no caso da pergunta [Ajuda em javascript e asp.net mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/18940/ajuda-em-javascript-e-asp-net-mvc), eu pesquiso exatamente o problema que estou tento `função javascript executa primeira vez`, então se nos resultados tivessem:

1. Ajuda em javascript e asp.net mvc
2. Função javascript só executa uma vez

É claro que eu clicaria na segunda, mesmo que fosse uma pergunta no Yahoo Respostas.

Eu penso que o título deve ser um resumo objetivo e extremamente direto do problema.

Comment: Pois é, eu vejo muito disso: "Dificuldade com linguagem X", "Ajuda no meu algoritmo", títulos que não querem dizer nada de absolutamente nada. Eu sou super a favor de editar títulos assim, e acho que o ideal seria que isso fosse a cultura do nosso site.

Comment: Então, é exatamente isso que quero dizer.

Comment: E eu estou concordando com você, talvez sendo um pouco repetitivo, mas concordando, rs..

Comment: Poxa @KaduAmaral, tinha que usar logo a minha pergunta? Me senti meio desvalorizado agora. ;((((... KKKK. Mas só pra constar, eu ainda era bem novato no SOpt nessa época da pergunta...

Comment: Kk, eu nem vi quem era o autor. Fiz a pesquiza e peguei uma das primeiras que vi @ErikThiago

Comment: =((((.. KKK. Me senti mal agora.

Comment: Não tem de se sentir mal @ÉrikThiago, todos nos já passamos por isso, é natural que as vezes nos editem as perguntas/respostas. É bom para nós e para o site, não tem de se sentir mal por isso.

Comment: Então, não tem nenhuma resposta/solução/sugestão para esse "problema"?

Comment: @JorgeB pô valeu demais ! Mas em relação a discussão levantada, acho uma boa ideia os títulos serem atualizados para um contexto de mais abrangência com o assunto abordado na pergunta....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sim, podemos alterar o título assim como podemos também alterar o conteúdo da postagem para torná-la mais clara.

Na verdade, não só podemos como somos incentivados a isso. Esse foi um dos motivos da criação das medalhas Intérprete, Aprimorador e Luminar. Pois de acordo com a [publicação no Metão](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239898/229289) que anunciou essas medalhas, citou:

> We're talking about rewarding folks that take a tiny bit more time out of their day just to write a more descriptive **title** so that folks can find the awesome answer that they wrote. Just doing that alone can make a big difference.

Em tradução livre:

> Nós estamos falando de recompensar pessoas que gastam um pouquinho a mais do tempo de seus dias para escrever um **título** mais descritivo para que outras pessoas possam achar a excelente resposta que ele escreveu. Apenas fazendo isso pode fazer uma diferença gigantesca.

A recompensa dada pela medalha parte do suposto que se a pessoa pontuou com a resposta ela possui habilidades de comunicação boas o suficiente para transmitir uma mensagem com clareza, além do mais essa pessoa *entendeu* a pergunta e entende sobre o assunto. O AP nem sempre sabe o que ele precisa, ou do quê ele precisa, mas quem tem o conhecimento do assunto sabe, caso é claro que a pergunta seja minimamente entendível.

Que nem no exemplo que você passou do `NaN`, o AP pode de repente ter pensado que o problema estava no mask, ou no *parse*, ou na divisão, ou no `if`, ou sabe-se lá onde. Ele simplesmente não sabia onde estava o problema, caso soubesse nem precisava criar uma pergunta :) E com isso os títulos no final das contas ficam do jeito que a gente sabe que eles ficam.

Entretanto, eu discordo que se o título do seu exemplo fosse `Função javascript só executa uma vez` seria bom, pois existem diversas maneiras diferentes de fazer um código que só rode pela primeira vez. Eu acho que um título que melhor representa o problema do AP seria:

> Não consigo fazer cálculos em JavaScript com números decimais

É só uma sugestão, podem existir outros bons títulos para essa pergunta também.