# Título longo demais é aceitável?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Estou voltando com uma dúvida simples, que [já foi debatida](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3827/edi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-t%C3%ADtulo-para-facilitar-as-buscas), mas parece que a resposta aceita não está sendo aplicada corretamente.

Algumas vezes me deparo com questões que possuem um título muito longo, [como essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/299052/2). Está certo que esse é um caso que cabe uma edição para melhorar, afinal há palavras que não são relevantes no título. Infelizmente certas vezes eu não posso alterar por não ter conhecimento no assunto, então espero alguém fazer a edição. Porém, fazendo uma pesquisa [simples pelo Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/pt/query/852174/long-titles) descobri que há muitos títulos maiores que 140 caracteres. Claro que essa é uma singela pesquisa, inclusive algumas já constam fechadas e a quantidade de caracteres foi baseado no limite de um tweet antigo. Mas é aí que algumas dúvidas surgem.

Qual o limite de caracteres de um título, devemos diminuir? Uma pergunta com um título tão longo assim deve ser editada? Se sim, isso está aplicado? Devemos dar mais atenção com relação a isso ou é irrelevante? É a hora de uma "força tarefa"?

Alguns exemplos:

- [Tenho que criar um programa de cadastramento de filme, porém eu rodo o programa e ele da erro e eu não entendi oq pq não roda, podem me ajudar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/252697/tenho-que-criar-um-programa-de-cadastramento-de-filme-por%C3%A9m-eu-rodo-o-programa)
- [Assistência remota e função CreateRectRgn: Como ajustar retângulo na mesma posição na tela (com base na tela do servidor), em outro computador?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104139/assist%C3%AAncia-remota-e-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-createrectrgn-como-ajustar-ret%C3%A2ngulo-na-mesma-posi%C3%A7)
- [Como migrar parte dos dados de uma TabelaA para uma TabelaB e referenciar o ID do item inserido na TabelaB em uma coluna da TabelaA em SQL Server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/259529/como-migrar-parte-dos-dados-de-uma-tabelaa-para-uma-tabelab-e-referenciar-o-id-d)
- [Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.name: CTS_EX_ACT_VW_DESCR$0 (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/262401/expected-condition-failed-waiting-for-element-to-be-clickable-by-name-cts-ex)
- [Como pegar o numero separado pela função inteiro logo abaixo e ordena-lo corretamente como descrito na duvida principal em negrito na pergunta no C++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/65816/como-pegar-o-numero-separado-pela-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-inteiro-logo-abaixo-e-ordena-lo-correta)

Comment: O tamanho certo é o que descreve bem o problema com o mínimo de letras. Outras medidas acho que são artificiais.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Aceitável **é**, ideal **não**.

Existem muitos títulos, longos ou curtos que são péssimos para o entendimento da pergunta, e existem títulos com muita redundância, tipo "podem me ajudar?" ... até aonde sei todos que perguntam já estão buscando ajuda, isso é totalmente dispensável de se escrever.

É como pegar a fila para pagar conta de água e depois de 20 minutos de espera, na sua vez, você perguntar "é aqui que se paga a conta de água?".

Não tem necessidade e no mínimo a pessoa que fez essa pergunta esta um pouco confusa ou frustada ao chegar no local, no nosso caso no site.

Então se você puder, dispor de tempo, paciência e interesse **edite os títulos**, sejam curtos, sejam longos, o que importa é torna-los úteis e fáceis de se outros usuários encontrarem.

Tanto em títulos, quanto no corpo das postagem se puder sempre remova:

- Redundâncias
- Ruídos (exemplos: Bom dia, boa tarde, boa noite, muito obrigado, por favor, preciso muito de ajuda, etc)
- torne mais fácil de buscar

Se fizermos isso em comunidade serão mais mãos trabalhando e poderemos dividir essas tarefas e até orientar os novatos.

Comment: Concordo. O campo de inserção dos títulos possui um limite de 300 caracteres. Acho isso muito. Algumas perguntas possuem o corpo da mensagem até menores que isso e bem entendível.