# Títulos melhores ajudam no SEO aqui do SO também?

Tags: debate, perguntas

Gostaria de saber se os títulos dos posts aqui do SOpt são o item mais importante pras buscas no Google?

Pergunto isso porque às vezes vejo títulos do tipo: "Preciso de ajuda com JavaScript", entre outros (que eu mesmo, quando era mais leigo em programação, já criei) e não sei se é correto editar totalmente o título do post da pessoa, ou deixar como está.

Comment: Sim, deve-se editar um título desses. Tem dois problemas o título, o facto de não dizer nada sobre o que será o assunto da pergunta e o uso das tags no título.

Comment: Mehror do que pensar no SEO é fazer [edição do título para facilitar as buscas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3827/70).

Answer (score 7):

Sim, totalmente. Título é usado pelo menos como `<title>` do HTML e ajuda no SEO sim. Olha a sua pergunta (só as principais):

```
<title>T&#237;tulos melhores ajudam no SEO aqui do SO tamb&#233;m? - Stack Overflow em Portugu&#234;s Meta</title>
<meta property="og:url" content="https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7176/t&#237;tulos-melhores-ajudam-no-seo-aqui-do-so-tamb&#233;m"/>
<meta name="twitter:title" property="og:title" itemprop="title name" content="T&#237;tulos melhores ajudam no SEO aqui do SO tamb&#233;m?" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed para a pergunta &#39;T&#237;tulos melhores ajudam no SEO aqui do SO tamb&#233;m?&#39;" href="/feeds/question/7176">
<h1 itemprop="name"><a href="/questions/7176/t%c3%adtulos-melhores-ajudam-no-seo-aqui-do-so-tamb%c3%a9m" class="question-hyperlink">T&#237;tulos melhores ajudam no SEO aqui do SO tamb&#233;m?</a></h1>
```

Tem a ver com o que que postei em [Baixa qualidade em perguntas de novatos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7165/101). Todo mundo cansou de arrumar essas coisas e o objetivo do SOpt está se perdendo (atender outras pessoas mais até que o usuário que pergunta), viramos um fórum.

É mais que correto editar um título assim, este tipo de título não deveria sequer ser permitido. Só não posso obrigar ninguém fazê-lo.

Answer (score 4):

Só para acrescentar mais informação ao que já foi dito, um mau titulo também prejudica bastante nas pesquisas dentro do StackoverFlow.

Isto é bem comum quando você tenta ver se já existe uma duplicada de uma pergunta. Se o titulo não é descritivo então nenhuma das perguntas que já tem a resposta que pretende irão aparecer. Na verdade, não haverá forma de chegar a nenhuma dessas respostas a não ser procurando pelo usuário que fez a pergunta/resposta e navegando nelas.

Até mesmo quando uma dessas perguntas é linkada em alguma resposta ou pergunta, a pessoa que lê vê-se obrigada a clicar para saber o que tem, pois o titulo não é descritivo.

Por isso quanto mais descritivo for o título mais organizado e pesquisavel fica todo o nosso conteudo.