# Editar título cujo contexto e resolução não condizem

Tags: debate

Tópico alvo: 
[Como utilizar múltiplas condições dentro de um if](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75540/como-utilizar-m%C3%BAltiplas-condi%C3%A7%C3%B5es-com-jquery)

Tenho dúvida se devo editar o título pois não condiz com o contexto e a resolução.

Geralmente opto por manter o título original, por mais estranho que seja tecnicamente, porque outros podem ter a mesma dúvida. Se editar para algo muito técnico, os novatos ficam perdidos de qualquer forma.

Contudo, acho que nesse caso deveria ser editado.

Penso em algo bem amigável para novatos em programação como "**condições if else não funcionam**".

Há algum impedimento para tal alteração?

Há alguns meses, fiz essa mesma pergunta, porém, a situação era um pouco diferente:
[Dúvida em editar um título para algo mais apropriado e técnico](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2679/d%C3%BAvida-em-editar-um-t%C3%ADtulo-para-algo-mais-apropriado-e-t%C3%A9cnico)

Comment: Então, eu sempre penso bem antes de criar o título, justamente pra viabilizar que outras pessoas com o mesmo problema encontrem com facilidade, e em geral utilizo as palavras chave que estava usando pra pesquisar... Neste caso eu tentei seguir mais ou menos [o título de um tópico do SOen que era sobre javascript (e à partir do qual não tinha conseguido resolver)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710442/how-to-specify-multiple-conditions-in-an-if-statement-in-javascript)... Estava olhando agora, e esta pergunta já teve 64k views(!)...

Comment: Mas se a comunidade entender proveitoso, por mim tudo bem mudar. Abraços.

Comment: pelo que entendi vc fez de propósito, certo? Mesmo que tenha sido uma ideia originada de uma pergunta feita no SOen, não quer dizer que se está no SOen, é bom copiar devido aos "views"..  São ambientes muito distintos. Então eu subentendi que o seu intuito é ganhar visibilidade e consequentemente engajamento e pontos... Particularmente falando, fica uma péssima imagem quando vem de um usuário com nível razoável de reputação.. tanto aqui como no SOen ou qualquer outro site da rede.

Comment: foi apenas opinião. Se eu vejo dessa forma vc deveria tirar proveito disso ao invés de agir dessa forma desnecessária. Assim como interpretei dessa forma, outros podem tb ver o mesmo. Não te negativei, raramente dou negativo para alguém, pelo contrário, falo de frente.. para esclarecer.  Aí vc vem aqui e vomita essas coisas nada  a ver...

Comment: Eu já submeti algumas alterações de título, e uso o seguinte critério: O título atual: a) Nunca serviria para alguém com esse problema encontrar essa pergunta e b) Vendo o título, eu nunca imaginaria que a pergunta é essa. Se os dois critérios forem true, eu mudo sem dó (submeto a mudança). Muitas vezes as pessoas colocam um título que é mais o tema do que o problema em si.

Answer (score 5):

Edições no título não são um problema. Elas tendem a requerer mais cuidado por serem a primeira impressão de um post, mas se um título causa confusão, ou não representa a pergunta de alguma maneira, ou apresenta outro problema, deve sim ser editado.

A palavra chave é *cuidado*. Não há como quantificar objetivamente o que é um bom título, ou um mau título, portanto edições devem idealmente ser reservadas para casos em que o novo título é *óbviamente* melhor que o anterior. Não apenas quando você discorda do título atual.

Esse discernimento entre *"eu teria feito diferente"* e *"este título está errado"* é essencial para evitar uma alteração desnecessária que pode causar muito mais dano que melhorias.

Nesse caso específico, seu título sugerido ("Condições if e else não funcionam") não me parece melhorar em nada o título atual ("Como utilizar múltiplas condições com jQuery"). Não é mais objetivo, não é mais descritivo, não é mais representativo do problema.

Não quer dizer que o título atual seja absolutamente perfeito, mas ele precisaria ser substituido por algo substancialmente melhor. Caso contrário é só uma troca de seis por meia-dúzia, que não causa ganho algum.

Comment: obrigado. O primeiro motivo em debater isso aqui foi para evitar modificar o título e causar um mal estar. Infelizmente o AP não entendeu e levou para outro foco o assunto (apagou os comentários ofensivos, deixando os meus no vácuo.). Quanto ao título que "sugeri" ("Condições if e else não funcionam"). Foi meramente um exemplo. Mas discordo de que não mudaria em nada a situação atual. O motivo é que JQuery nada tem a ver com o assunto, por isso seria mais relevante uma alteração para algo similar ou igual ao sugerido.

Comment: Lembrando que a sugestão não é uma imposição. Não vou ficar nervoso como alguns ficam.. rsrs O novo título sugerido é focado naquele público bastante leigo, os iniciantes em programação. Por isso os termos são bastante genéricos. E, ao meu ver, modifica bastante e dá maior valor ao tópico, em relação ao título atual.